# Can a person I sent messages on Skype but it is not in my skype contact see when I was online and when I was last time online

Tags: skype

I sent some messages and contact request which is deleted i guess, to this one person, can that person see when I was online or timestamp when I was online last time on Skype. So Im not on his contact list, but I did sent him messages, can he somehow see when I was online last time?

Comment: If he just declined your request does it matter?

Comment: its matters to me, a looooooooot.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want that person to see your status then you can simply block them. From [Can I hide my online status from specific contacts..](http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/Can-I-hide-my-online-status-from-specific-contacts/td-p/457705):

> you temporarily block them when you don't want those certain contacts to see you online.  When you block a certain contact, you will appear just as "offline" on their ends.  You can block then unblock contacts anytime, and they will receive no notifications about your actions.

This would have the benefit that if they *do* accept your request then they still wouldn't see your status or activities.